# How to use the QGraphicsItem::setPos() function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I can't figure out how the `setPos()` function of the `QGraphicsItem` class works.

My `Rect` class has no parent, so its origin is relative to the scene.

I try to put the rectangle back at (0, 0) after it is moved with the mouse but it is placed in a different place depending on where I had moved it.
I suppose that means that the origin of the scene moves but what causes this change?

```cpp
class Rect : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    Rect(): QGraphicsItem()
    {
        setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override
    {
            setPos(0, 0);
            update();
            QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
            return QRectF(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

private:
};
```

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QGraphicsScene scene;
        QGraphicsView view(&scene);
        Rect obj;
        scene.addItem(&obj);

        view.show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event)` call moves the item to where the mouse is, so the previous `setPos` call has no effect. `setFlag(ItemIsMovable)` tells `QGraphicsItem` that it should move with the mouse when dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a QGraphicsView you initially accept the default settings. A standard setting is, for example, that it is horizontally centered.

[image]

Another factor is that the default area size is probably up to the maximum size.

what you can do set a custom size for the scene. You do that with `graphicsView->setSceneRect(0,0,300,300);` (for example)

```
    scene       = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(0,0, 300,300);
    
    rectItem    = new QGraphicsRectItem(0,0, 100, 100);
    rectItem->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkMagenta, 2));
    rectItem->setBrush(QGradient(QGradient::SaintPetersburg));
    rectItem->setPos(190,10);

    scene->addItem(rectItem);
```

[image] [image]

So in summary: if you want to work with fixed values. maybe it is better to know the total size. (that was not clear from your code, that's why I gave this example)

Comment: Thanks, resizing the scene each time the view is changed seems to fix the problem

Comment: It's really just for the eye. the `setPos()` still works as it should. If you take two objects, you will see that this function does its job. If you don't want the size to be fixed, you can just change the `vertical` and `horizontal` align for the `QGraphicsView` (`left-top, left`).